# How can new gods bring down the actual theocratic system?

Tags: magic, religion, supernatural

As part of the new deities plan, they must bring down the elder gods in their world to create enough chaos to 'starve' them. The religious focus is simple:

- Old gods are the actual rulers in the universe, but they're not omnipotent or immortal, they're just ageless reality warpers and need big amount of life force to survive (almost harvesting humans).
- Gods are divided in two different ideologies: some believe universe must be controlled to avoid it's self destruction even if they must trample the weak ones, while the others think universe must follow its chaos path and 'reborn' from destruction.
- Gods send angels to murder the non believers and collect their energy and ask the believer for sacrifices, mostly made when the chruch arrives in every kingdom so priestess can act as catalyzers (mostly nomadic cultists corrupted by the gods).
- Elder gods know about the new deities and they're scared as hell with the idea of being replaced, so they made normal people believe this new deities are evil and heretics.
- They ***NEED*** humans since they produce most life energy compared to other lifeforms.

About the new deities:

- They're supernatural beings that grow in mortal shells.
- As mortals they have almost unlimited life energy growth
- Most of them are true neutral, so they don't care about mankind at all (except life and death)
- Fate deity is human, but he comes from a different realm where mankind is actually fighting against angels (no Evangelion reference).
- Life deity is a starborn, almost a celestial beings who was raised by gods before they knew she was one of them
- Death deity is a mistborn, celestial too, almost used by the chaos faction for mass murdering and wiping civilizations.
- Matter/Energy goddess is almost a wolf person (demi human with wolf traits), one of the most hated races since gods consider them unholy creations.
- These deities will eventually overcome the elder gods since they control concepts, but are constantly hunted and killed so they can't grow.
- World has heavy magic.

How can these beings start a religious revolution to take down their enemies and stop their supremacy?

Comment: Since the new gods don't seem to need humans for anything, killing them all and then making their own sentient species once the old gods are dead seem to be the easiest solution.

Comment: @A.C.A.C.wouldn't nuke on spot be too hard to follow for a novel?

Comment: Do the new gods need humans as badly as the old gods?  If not, @A.C.A.C.'s solution is the only sensible solution.  If so, then not caring about mankind doesn't make sense.  But, let's ignore that.  If they do need the humans as badly, then killing the humans kills all the gods.  That would make the fight psychological.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found as the plot in the novel you're going to write, I presume. Voting to close as _too story-based_.

Comment: @JBH death and life goddesses create/kill life, so it's mostly a concept for their existance (creating life and killing it gives them power), while Fate, Matter/energy, Time don't need such things.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer one:**

First:

> Old gods are [...] not omnipotent or immortal.

Second:

> Death deity

... exists. Send him, he'll handle the old Gods.

**Answer two.1:**

A. C. A. C.'s comment on the OP: Kill all of humanity and let Life create a new sentient species for them.

**Answer two.2:**

Kill a good amount of humanity, so that the life force of the remaining humans isn't enough for the old ones.

**Answer three:**

Let your new Gods only kill the priests. If the priests aren't protected by their gods, why should the rest of humanity still prey to them, if the evidently 'stronger' ones are right in front of them?

**Answer four.1:**

Let Life-deity and/or energy-goddess enhance some people, which worship them. This would put the believers of the New ones above the ones of the old gods.

**Answer four.2:**

Let Life-deity and Matter/Energie-goddess create an utopia somewhere, inviting people to them. "Look folks, our Realm is far superior to your current location."

**Answer five:**

Fate comes from a realm, where they already fight the angels. Let him call for some of his friends.

**Answer six:**

Made the believer of the old gods aware, just how much these gods suppresses them. With all the killing the non-believers and asking for sacrifices thingy. New ones neither need, nor want this from them.

**Answer seven:**

Fate is a human, right? Let him promise the common people to make some of them gods as well, if they serve him well. Up to you, if he really does that or not.

**Answer eight:**

> World has heavy magic

Let your New gods give humanity access to said magic. They will kill themself in a bunch of years, without any further input... If not in mere months.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to stop the gods' Supply of power. The gods get the power from two ways, one from the sacrifices of the Believers, two from the death of the unbelievers by the hands of the Angels/ lesser Spirit servants.

So first you need to stop the angels. Now the new Gods could try doing this themselves but there's only a handful of them against who knows how many angels, realistically and they need an army.  An army of powerful servants, their own Angels if you will. Perhaps the goddess of matter and the god of life can combine their powers to create such creatures.

Next you have to stop the Believers from sacrificing to the Gods. The most obvious way to do this is to start their own religion involving worship of them let them show themselves as not only more powerful but more benevolent deity who don't require human sacrifice. It will take some time but eventually more Believers will come to their side if they prove themselves to be better gods then the current ones they have. And those who stubbornly refuse to change their religion can be brought over by force if necessary.